# TypeScript - What does importing and exporting interfaces as type do?

Tags: typescript, types, import, interface, export

The TS docs mention interfaces and type aliases, but I can't seem to find much info on importing or exporting interfaces as `type` and was hoping to get some clarification:

For example an interface can be exported as:

```js
// located in ./MyInterface.ts
export interface MyInterface
{
    foo: string;
    bar: () => number;
}

export type {MyInterface as MyInterfaceType}
```

and it can be imported as:
`import {MyInterface} from "./MyInterface"`
*or*
`import type {MyInterface} from "./MyInterface"`
*or*
`import {MyInterfaceType} from "./MyInterface"`
*or*
`import type {MyInterfaceType} from "./MyInterface"`
Can anyone explain the difference in behavior between each interface import?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript 3.8 adds a new syntax for [type-only imports and exports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export)

```
export type { MyInterface as MyInterfaceType }
```

Only export `MyInterface` type with alias `MyInterfaceType`.

> `export type` only provides an export that can be used for type contexts, and is also erased from TypeScript’s output.

And

```
export interface MyInterface
{
    foo: string;
    bar: () => number;
}
```

It's a ECMAScript 2015 module named export.

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, JavaScript has a concept of modules. TypeScript shares this concept.

> Any declaration (such as a variable, function, class, type alias, or interface) can be exported by adding the export keyword.

See [Exporting a declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#exporting-a-declaration)

Comment: First off, thank you sooooo much for that link to the "type-only imports and exports". I never would of found that myself! But don't interfaces get erased from TypeScript output too? I thought Interfaces were essentially types that can be extended by other interfaces and/or implemented by classes. While literal `type`s are like interfaces, except they can't be extended (but can be combined via unions) and bound to objects OR primitives?